# Calculate duration between multiple date ranges without overlapping date time

Tags: java

Please see below SQL codes. There are multiple start dates and end dates aggregated for the same job.

On the Java side, I want to calculate the total elapsed time for rows with type = 0. It's easy to achieve this with Duration.between(start, end) but I can't get rid of the overlapped time between the lines. How can I get rid of overlapsed times?

```
create table timeline
(
    start_time datetime(6) null,

    end_time   datetime(6) null,
    type       int         null,
);
```

```
INSERT INTO timeline (start_time, end_time, type)
VALUES ('2022-07-29 08:30:00.414000', '2022-07-29 19:56:33.414000', 1);

INSERT INTO timeline (start_time, end_time, type)
VALUES ('2022-07-29 15:30:03.412754', '2022-07-29 15:57:03.965432', 0);

INSERT INTO timeline (start_time, end_time, type)
VALUES ('2022-07-29 15:40:03.414000', '2022-07-29 16:32:03.004323', 0);

INSERT INTO timeline (start_time, end_time, type)
VALUES ('2022-07-29 16:50:03.643231', '2022-07-29 17:35:03.234562', 0);
```

Based on this data at hand, there are two things to consider:

1. Overlap time
2. Idle time

Conclusion, the 3 rows with type = 0, should give us two lines after the conversion:

1. **Start Time:** 2022-07-29 15:30:03.412754 - **End Time:** 2022-07-29 16:32:03.004323
2. **Start Time:** 2022-07-29 16:50:03.643231 - **End Time:** 2022-07-29 17:35:03.234562

Comment: Isn't it simply the duration between the minimum start time and the maximum end time?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Unfortunately no. Please check the last two lines. There are 18 idle minutes between two dates.

Comment: Loop over all resulting rows, find out the smallest start time and the biggest end time.

Comment: @f1sh Unfortunately it's not the right approach. There may be idle date times between dates. It even exists between the last two example rows.

Comment: Maybe something like this would work: 1. Put all starting times and end times in a List (or similar). 2. Sort that list by starting time. 3. Iterate over List and for each element A check if another following element B starting time is between starting and end time of A. If yes combine those 2 values to a new range with starting time of A and end time of the maximum of either A or B (whichever is bigger/later). 4. Continue until no overlaps are found. 5. Now just sum up the duration of all ranges in your new list with the combined ranges.

Comment: @BerkanAslan but what about the first example row? That ranges from 8:30 to 19:56, so it includes all the other rows. So this is not the best example.

Comment: @f1sh In the question he wrote "I want to calculate the total elapsed time for rows with type = 0". The first row has type 1, so you should ignore it.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I would like to let you know that I am not able to simulate your approach. Is there only one list that contains start times and end times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

- by iterating over the rows from the database, create a list of job durations that take the overlaps into account

  - if a new row overlaps an existing JobDuration in the list, the existing element will be modified with the new start and/or end date
- this list can now be turned into duration values

Take a look at this code:

```
class Scratch {

  static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<JobDuration> durations = new ArrayList<>();
    List<JobDuration> newJobs = List.of(
            //commented because it has type=1
            /*JobDuration.of("2022-07-29 08:30:00.414000", "2022-07-29 19:56:33.414000"),*/
            JobDuration.of("2022-07-29 15:30:03.412754", "2022-07-29 15:57:03.965432"),
            JobDuration.of("2022-07-29 15:40:03.414000", "2022-07-29 16:32:03.004323"),
            JobDuration.of("2022-07-29 16:50:03.643231", "2022-07-29 17:35:03.234562")
    );
    newJobs.stream().forEach(d -> addDuration(durations, d));

    Collections.sort(durations, Comparator.comparing(JobDuration::getStart));
    System.out.println(durations);
    durations.stream().map(JobDuration::getDuration).forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  private static void addDuration(List<JobDuration> durations, JobDuration newJdr) {
    if(durations.isEmpty()) {
      durations.add(newJdr);
      return;
    }
    boolean overlap = false;
    for(JobDuration j:durations) {
      //overlaps at the start?
      if(newJdr.start.isBefore(j.start) && newJdr.end.isAfter(j.start)) {
        j.start = newJdr.start;
        overlap = true;
      }
      //overlaps at the end?
      if(newJdr.start.isBefore(j.end) && newJdr.end.isAfter(j.end)) {
        j.end = newJdr.end;
        overlap = true;
      }
      //is completely inside?
      if(newJdr.start.isAfter(j.start) && newJdr.end.isBefore(j.end)){
        overlap = true;
      }
    }
    if(!overlap) {
      //it did not overlap anywhere, so it's a new entry in the list
      durations.add(newJdr);
    }
  }


  public static class JobDuration {
    LocalDateTime start;
    LocalDateTime end;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "JobDuration{" +
              "start=" + start +
              ", end=" + end +
              '}';
    }

    public JobDuration(LocalDateTime pStart, LocalDateTime pEnd) {
      start = pStart;
      end = pEnd;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStart() {
      return start;
    }

    public static JobDuration of(String sStart, String sEnd) {
      return new JobDuration(LocalDateTime.parse(sStart, FORMATTER), LocalDateTime.parse(sEnd, FORMATTER));
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
      return Duration.between(start, end);
    }
  }
}
```

Running this code prints the list (with the 2 non-overlapping time frame) and the Duration of each one.

```
[JobDuration{start=2022-07-29T15:30:03.412754, end=2022-07-29T16:32:03.004323}, JobDuration{start=2022-07-29T16:50:03.643231, end=2022-07-29T17:35:03.234562}]
PT1H1M59.591569S
PT44M59.591331S
```

This means this code combines the first two entries, because they overlap. The third entry does not overlap anywhere, so it results in its own duration.

Comment: Thanks. I tested with different date time ranges. It works consistently. In addition, the simple and important point here is that the data should be sorted by start time.

Comment: Hi! I edited the code and added the sorting.